# Advice for order in big javascript file

Tags: javascript

I started creating a javascript file in Sublime Text with a few lines and a few functions, but over days passed the file was growing and growing and now it has around 600 lines with about 40 functions.

So I keep scrolling up and down for writing or reading code. And I think that that it's not a good workflow. How can i be more organized with javascript code. Is there a technique that professionals use for that, or a tool?

Comment: A good practice is to modularize your files, so that each individual JS file only does the bare minimum. Look into CommonJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

600 lines is not so much, yet. What you can do is namespace your code (separate it according to functionality). For example:

Lets say you have a js file with a bunch of functions

```
function formatDate(date){ ... }

function calcAge(birthdate){ ... }

function removeAccents(string){ ... }

function resizeImage(img){ ... }

... and many more ...
```

You can go ahead and separate functions by category, in this case we could group all the functions that deal with dates. All the ones that deal with strings and the ones that handle images.

```
// we create a global namespace, on main.js
var MyCoolProject = {};

// then we include string.js, and put all the string functions here
MyCoolProject.string = {
    removeAccents: function(string){ ... }
};

// on date.js, we put all date functions
MyCoolProject.date = {
    formatDate: function(date){ ... },
    calcAge: function(birthdate){ ... }
};

// so on with image.js
MyCoolProject.img = {
    resizeImage: function(date){ ... }
};
```

This way you have several smaller files that handle a specific kind of logic and you would call your functions like this:

```
function doSomethingAwesome(str){
    var awesomeString = MyCoolProject.string.awesomize(str);
    alert(awesomeString);
}
```

You also benefit by having more maintainable code and avoid collisions. Collisions happen when you include another script that happens to have a function with the same name as yours. If this happens, only the last included function will be executed. By namespacing your code you prevent this.

**Keep in mind**

You will have more files, this means more `<script>` tags in your html in which sometimes the order matters! You should eventually use build tools like grunt or gulp to concatenate and minimize all the js into one single scripts.js file. This way you have full control over your code during development. But once in production your site will make only one request for a js file which should make your site load faster.

Also, the namespacing method used here is my personal preference but in js you can achieve the same behavior through other patterns like prototypes, closures, commonjs, etc so you could research these and see which one fits your personal preference. There is not one better than the other, just one that will serve as a tool to make you build it faster and better.